# A doubt regarding the solution of an eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the following given equations:

$$ \Omega = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{2k}{m} & \frac{k}{m} \\ \frac{k}{m} & -\frac{2k}{m} \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\Omega |I \rangle = -\omega^{2}_{I}|I \rangle \; , \; \Omega |II \rangle = -\omega^{2}_{II}|II \rangle$$

Where $\Omega$ is a linear operator, $|I \rangle$ and $|II \rangle$ are its eigenvectors and $-\omega^{2}_{I}$ and $-\omega^{2}_{II}$ its eigenvalues. The context is a system of coupled oscillators.

---

Here is my attempt to solve the eigenvalue problem:
$$ \det(\Omega - (-\omega^{2}I)) = 0 \therefore \det(\Omega + \omega^{2}I) = 0$$
$$ \Longrightarrow \begin{vmatrix} \Omega_{11} + \omega^{2} & \Omega_{12} \\ \Omega_{21} & \Omega_{22} + \omega^{2} \end{vmatrix} = 0$$
$$ (\Omega_{11} + \omega^{2})(\Omega_{22} + \omega^{2}) = \Omega_{12} \cdot \Omega_{21}$$
$$ \omega^{4} - \omega^{2}\left(\frac{4k}{m}\right) + \left( \frac{3k^{2}}{m^{2}} \right) = 0$$

Let $\omega^{2} = Q$. Hence

$$ Q^{2} - Q\left(\frac{4k}{m}\right) + \left( \frac{3k^{2}}{m^{2}} \right) = 0$$

Solving using the quadratic formula, yields
$$ Q = \frac{2k}{m} \pm \frac{k}{m} \Longrightarrow $$
$$ \omega^{2} = \frac{3k}{m} \; , \; \omega^{2} = \frac{k}{m} \therefore \omega = \left[ +\sqrt{\frac{3k}{m}} \; , \; -\sqrt{\frac{3k}{m}} \; , + \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} \; , -\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} \right]$$

---

The problem is that the book says there are only 2 eigenvalues, and they are the ones with the positive signal that I have found above. Indeed, finding only 2 eigenvalues should be the natural, since we are in a bidimensional orthonormal basis. In the past exercises, instead of calling the eigenvalue of $-\omega^{2}$, I was used to call of just $\omega$. By doing this procedure of calling $-\omega^{2}$ I have found two extra eigenvalues. The author of the book, Shankar, says that he called the eigenvalue of $-\omega^{2}$ by anticipating the fact that $\Omega$ has eigenvalues of this type. Nevertheless, when he continues the solution of the example, he says that the eigenvalues are just the ones with the positive signal that I have found above.

Giving further context, $k$ is a string constant (real), and $m$ is the mass of a block (real). The author **do says** that the eigenvalues are **real.**

Could anyone say what am I missing here? I bet it is something simple but that I am not being able to see. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you defined the eigenvalue as $-\omega^2$, so you shouldn't solve for $\omega$ to find the eigen values of $\Omega$, but rather $-\omega^2$. This does lead to two values, not 4.

The two eigenvalues are: $\frac{-3k}{m}$ and $\frac{-k}{m}$. The possible values of $\omega$ are not eigenvalues of the matrix in general, but exactly the values computed in the question.

Comment: I see. So instead of taking the square root from both sides when I found $\omega^{2}$ was I supposed just to multiply by $(-1)$ from both sides? This way I would get the results without a square root, and in the book he says that the actual eigenvalues are the square root of those terms.

Comment: I solved the problem again, but calling the general eigenvalue by $\omega$. After that I just related my $omega$ with the specific $\omega_{I}$ and $\omega_{II}$. It worked and I obtained the right eigenvalues. Thank you!